# How to you render JS.ERB files that is in another controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

i do not quite understand what is wrong with my code - it is even causing my server to hang up.

What i need to do is for the controller to return a JS script that when executed, will append a rendered partial to my $(".reviews")

```
# test.html.erb
$.getScript("/test");

# controller
  wants.js do
    render :partial => "/shared/activity"
  end

#/shared/activity.js.erb
$("#reviews").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => /shared/activity )) %>");
```

I suspect there is something wrong with the way i am asking for the render in my controller. In fact, it throws up all sorts of weird errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have both `activity.js.erb` and `activity.html.erb`, it will probably help if you specify which one you want to render:

```
# test.html.erb
$.getScript("/test");

# controller
wants.js do
  render :partial => "/shared/activity.js.erb"
end

#/shared/activity.js.erb
$("#reviews").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => '/shared/activity.html.erb' )) %>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You call yourself in your partial. So you have an infinite loop.

Comment: What would be the right way to do it? I am puzzled- i cannot find good examples in the rails docs

Comment: What you want? There are no output in your partial.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I want the controller to render the activity.js.erb, which in turns return /shared/activity.HTML.erb.

Comment: I need the "/shared/activity.js.erb" to render "/shared/activity.html.erb". I have updated the question to reflect that I need to run javascript code in the js file, in order to render a html partial in my main file